# Setting a property in java:comp/env?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, components, environment

I write Java projects with Eclipse and I wonder if there is a way to set a new property in java:comp/env via java itself?
Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java:comp/env` is read-only at runtime, so **no**.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from http://v1.dione.zcu.cz/java/docs/jndi-1.2/tutorial/beyond/misc/policy.html

> The JNDI does not define any naming policy on its own. However, one important platform that does define a limited set of naming policies for using the JNDI is the Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition (J2EETM). It defines a logical namespace that application components (such as Enterprise JavaBeans, servlets, and JavaServer Pages (JSP)) can use to name resources, components, and other data. The namespace is provided to a component by its container, the entity that executes the component. Typically, a component has a deployment descriptor that contains, among other data, information about the logical names and types of resources and components that the component needs or references.

By looking an only the last two sentences , I would say that it is impossible to set these properties pro grammatically